# Choose a specific low variable based on playa via stub?

Tags: playa, low-variables

Ok I have brands for products stored as a Playa so I can do various things with them...obviously simple things like:

`{cf_paper_brand}
     {title}
{/cf_paper_brand}`

However, later I want to include a list of articles based on that product's brand.  I am storing these related articles in low variables(of playas) -

`lv_brand1_articles, lv_brand2_articles`

etc.

Thus my basic issue is I want to retrieve/choose the appropriate low variable based on the playa brand field.

This seems like it should be easy, and certainly I can do it with a bunch of conditionals I guess.  But I am thinking there must be a more elegant solution...basically, I just need to get the brand title once and then use this in a few spots as a 'stub' when retrieving the low variable

In pseudo code:

```
if cf_product_brand == "brand1" then
    {exp:low_variables:parse var="{lv_brand1_articles}" var_prefix="brand_articles"}
        {brand_articles:title}
    {/exp:low_variables:parse}
else if cf_product_brand == "brand1"
    {exp:low_variables:parse var="{lv_brand2_articles}" var_prefix="brand_articles"}
        {brand_articles:title}
    {/exp:low_variables:parse}
else if....
```

etc... but for a LOT of brands, and I have related articles, links, and files.  So I will end up with a block of 30+ conditionals - which sucks.  Basically, I want to keep this mess of conditionals out of my template or at least in one spot in the template.

SO - If could set a stub of the brand title somehow, then retrieve {lv_{stub}_articles} - that would work....but I can't seem to do this.  I have tried with stash but I am new to all the parse order issues and getting confused.  I am thinking maybe I need to use a low variable with a pre_parse thing but can't quite seem to get it ...

Any help much appreciated!!  I am relatively new to EE and Stack Exchange etc.  Hope I have asked correctly!

(And note - the brand is not available in the segment_x variables as it's not in the URL.  I could in theory put it there, but I'd really prefer not to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for future reference, this is how I did it:

```
                {exp:playa:children field='cf_paper_brand' var_prefix="brand"}
                    {exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_links_{brand:url_title}" var_prefix="brand_links"}
                             ****** B- {brand_links:link_text}{brand_links:link_description}
                    {/exp:low_variables:parse}
                {/exp:playa:children}
```

Predictably, this seems obvious now.